# Can an instance be queried by Flag-ed enum property?

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Suppose I have this class definition:

```
  [Flags]
  enum Permissions
  {
      Read = 0,
      Write = 1,
      Execute = 2
  }
 class User
  {
      public string Name { get;set; }
      public Permissions Permissions { get;set; }
  }
```

and then an instance of user is stored with multiple permissions.

Is there a way to query users by permission ?

```
dbGet<User>(x=>x.Permissions.....) // what goes as a predicate?
```

Comment: Actually looking at how its stored in db - its probably a good idea not to query by this field, and if I need multiple permissions - make it a separate table.